# PHP regex: remove all chars from start and end

Tags: php, regex

The aim is to remove all starting and ending `\n` from a string. There can be none, one and many `\n` at the start and end, independently in number.

I thought on using `preg_replace` with a regex expression. But the following test is not working:

```php
$text = "asd\nasd\nasd\nasd\n";
//$text = "\n\nasd\nasd\nasd\nasd\n";
$text = preg_replace('/^(\\n)*(?!\\n)(.*)(?<!\\n)(\\n)*$/', '$2', $text);
var_dump($text);
```

With [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) the group 2 (see `$2` above) is exactly the middle of the string, without starting and ending `\n`.

Questions:

1. What is wrong with my PHP code above? Why can't I replace the full text with only the middle part? Should I really remove start/end and not replacing with the middle part?
2. When I use the regex expression `/^(\\n)*(.*)(\\n)*$/` instead of the one given above, do I have any disadvantage? In the regex expression above I try "start with \n - any char except \n - any char wanted but not end with \n - end with \n". And in the shorter expression I just list none, one or many \n at start and end. But could this be a problem, that e.g. only one of many `\n` at start/end will be replaced and some will not be replaced? Is there a guarantee, that a `\n` will not be part of the `(.*)` in the middle?

**EDIT with solution**

1. solution: this basic example would also be possible to solve with the PHP `trim` function. (In my case the `preg_replace` had a special reason, so for me [this answer from ryszard-czech worked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65602834/5229688))
2. attention: the string `$text` must be with double quotes `"` and not with single quotes `'` because there is a significant difference in PHP!

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use `trim()`?

Comment: `$string = trim ( $string , "\r\n" );` should do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```php
$text = preg_replace('/^\n+|\n+\z/', '', $text);
```

**Explanation**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n+                      '\n' (newline) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n+                      '\n' (newline) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \z                       the end of the string
```

Comment: of course, just deleting the not wanted parts is a better solution then to wrap everything. Thanks a lot. But for my second question: Is a `\n` in a `(\n)*(.*)` strong enough, to delete all `\n` or can it be e.g. in `\n\n\nasd` only to delete one or two `\n` and let multiple `\n` in the `(.*)` group? (Same for `(.*)(\n)*`.)

Comment: @christopher2007 `/^(\\n)*(.*)(\\n)*$/` might work, yes. `.` does not match line  feeds.